# How to Remove CSS line-through

Tags: html, css

I am trying to remove the `text-decoration:line-through;` style applied to my element and I cannot seem to be able to do so. I have tried `text-decoration:none;` but it does not work.

When I apply `text-decoration:underline;` to `span`, it seems that instead of replacing the `line-through` style the browser adds the `underline` style.

I know I can always re-write my HTML so the elements that require a `line-through` has their own class. I'm wondering if there is an alternative other then restructuring my HTML.

http://jsfiddle.net/wshHW/

```
<style>
p { text-decoration:line-through; }
span { text-decoration:none; }
</style>

<p>Foo <span>bar</span></p>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I know I can always re-write my HTML so the elements that require a `line-through` has their own class. I'm wondering if there is an alternative other then restructuring my HTML.

Not really. The behavior you see is totally [by design](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#lining-striking-props); ancestors will always propagate their text decorations to certain descendants, and conversely you can't affect an ancestor's text decoration from within a descendant.

There isn't a very viable alternative to restructuring, currently, although [`text-decoration-skip` from the upcoming CSS3 text decoration module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-decor-3/#text-decoration-skip-property) looks promising.

Comment: Shucks. I was hoping I could avoid that. Thanks.