# :not and text-decoration bug? Where to send this

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I think I have found a bug with the :not selector and I'm not sure where to submit bugs in CSS?

text-decoration will apply to the element in the :not

See this little codepen I have put together, the color is applied correctly however the underline is not.

https://codepen.io/miketricking/pen/YWKGyJ

```css
p {
    color: #000000;
}

:not(p) {
    color: red;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<h1>This is a heading</h1>

<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>

<div>This is some text in a div element.</div>
```

Comment: As @BoltClock said, the style is inherited from the `html` and `body` element, which can be seen in the browsers developer tools - [see here](http://s33.postimg.org/4e9ba8j4v/Screen_Shot_2016_05_25_at_13_47_53.png)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The text decoration is being applied to body and html, *along with* the h1 and div. All four elements match :not(p). The decoration from the body is being propagated to the p elements, and that is why you see a red underline (because its `color: red` declaration is being used to render the underline). This is not a bug in any browser or a mistake in the spec — on the contrary, this is [stated very deliberately in the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#lining-striking-props).

You can work around this by prepending `body` to your selector, but it will only work for top-level p elements, and not any that appear in other elements that would match :not(p) and propagate their text decorations anyway:

```css
p {
    color: #000000;
}

body :not(p) {
    color: red;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<h1>This is a heading</h1>

<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>

<div>This is some text in a div element.</div>
```

Unfortunately, you cannot prevent text decorations from being propagated to your p elements without changing their display type and breaking your layout in the process. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13693866/how-to-remove-css-line-through/13693884#13693884).

Comment: ah that makes perfect sense now! Thank you!